# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory(react npm test)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory

I have a react application.

---

While running npm test for that application it is failing with the **error:**

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: Please provide some more information. Look at [ask]

Comment: ==== JS stack trace =========================================
Security context: 00000221BFE25EE1 <JSObject>
    1: set [native weak-collection.js:~32] [pc=00000346DAE0E842](this=00000298F1
F7C221 <JSWeakMap>,key=00000034E54A5A11 <Object map = 0000039EF42AC789>,value=00
00019B45FF27C1 <Object map = 000003C48AB823B9>